# Is there a function or command in PHP to troubleshoot why data is not being inserted into a sql database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've been trying to get images to insert into my db for two weeks now. Just wondering if there was any way to get specific info on why in order to troubleshoot it (by means of a PHP function or something of the sort).

To be clearer, I'm asking if there is a way to generate an error message describing exactly the reason the data was not inserted, rather than writing out if/else statements for each individual situation (such as if not connected to database, wrong data type, etc.)

I've avoided code specifics as the last two got marked down and I'm about to be banned. Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked if there were any errors? https://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php

Comment: try\catch is as generic as you can get. standard with pdo

Comment: Thank you both for your answers.  I've tried what the first responder said, but am not getting anything back. Here's the relevant portion of the code if any one is feeling generous as to why it's not returning anything                                       $sql= "INSERT INTO IMAGE (ITEM_ID,IMAGE_ONE,IMAGE_TWO,IMAGE_THREE,IMAGE_FOUR) VALUES ('$introw','$a1','$i2','$i3','$i4')";
    
        echo "\nPDOStatement::errorInfo():\n";
$arr = $sql->errorInfo();
print_r($arr);                          It says I'm trying to run the function on a string.

Comment: As for the try/catch, I'll start looking into that now. Thank you both.

Comment: the try/catch method seems to be about the same as an if statement. If that's the case it doesn't help much. However, the first answer seems so promising if I can just figure out how to use it properly.

Comment: `$sql` is a string, so `$sql->errorInfo` is not right. if you want to debug some specific code you need to add it to the question, you did stary of however  wanting a generic approach

Comment: Trust me when I say I'd love help debugging this script. Been working on it for two weeks. Just scared to ask anything and show code because the first two times I got downvoted and I don't want to get banned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is, try `mysql_error` or `mysqli_error`

For example:

```
if (!mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName) VALUES ('Glenn')")){
    echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($con));
}
```

Comment: Tried to upvote this but since I have 0 rep it''s not public. Thank you very much. Gave me an error message which I can do something with :  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '7HYj{�������+=Oat�������2FZn' at line 1                                                                                       Assuming that I've either incorrectly gathered the image info or incorrectly configured the database attribute. Back to the drawing board haha. Thanks again!

Comment: you're always welcome! you may mark my answer as the correct one by clicking the "check" icon :D